# Tkinter on Python shows certain (monochrome) images messed up

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm trying to display images in Tkinter window and for some images, Tkinter displays them messed up. I've noticed it only happens for monochrome images, images without any color except for shades of grey.

[image: Here's the result window.]

The upper image (moon) is displayed incorrectly while the bottom one (rain) isn't. Here's the image viewed in MS Paint (left) and Photo viewer on Win10 (right). 
[image: Here's the image viewed in MS Paint (left) and Photo viewer on Win10 (right).]

I'm not sure what's causing this problem as I can't see the fault in image.

Since I took them from Yahoo Weather, here's [a link to the "faulty" moon image](https://s.yimg.com/os/weather/1.0.1/shadow_icon/60x60/clear_night@2x.png) and here's [a link to the "correct" rain image](https://s.yimg.com/os/weather/1.0.1/shadow_icon/60x60/rain_day_night@2x.png).

Lastly, here's my code:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tkinter.Tk()

# This part doesn't work as intended
display = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('moon.png'))
label = tkinter.Label(window, image=display)
label.pack()

# This part does
display2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('rain.png'))
label2 = tkinter.Label(window, image=display2)
label2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Note: I'm using a PIL fork *(as I understand PIL works only on Python 2)*: [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/)

Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: nobody perfect :) what is happend if you remove transparent background in file ?

Comment: I saved the image as .jpg and .gif and then it shows it correctly, but I need transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example shows that `ImageTk` does not handle well gray-scale images. But there are at least two workarounds to display correctly the pictures.

The first is not to use `ImageTk` at all. Indeed, since Tk 8.6, `PhotoImage` can load PNG images:

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
display = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='moon.png')
label = tkinter.Label(window, image=display)
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

But if you absolutely need to use `ImageTk`, you can change the mode of the picture to RGBA:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tkinter.Tk()

moon = Image.open('moon.png')
moon.mode = 'RGBA'   # force mode to RGBA
display = ImageTk.PhotoImage(moon)
label = tkinter.Label(window, image=display)
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```